# Drawbacks from using static fields in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an application written in ActionScript 3.0. It has several screens. All screens are unique. I don't need to create new screen at runtime.

I find it very comfortable to access screens via static variable that hold a reference to its screen. Does this method has some drawbacks or this is common way to do so?

Comment: I don't really know what is scene. Buy by saying screen I mean "Looby" screen, "Shop" screen, "Game" screen etc.

Comment: one disadvantage would be they stay in memory ALL the time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean with several screens. But if it is not, you should use layers and by this you can manage their visibilities and children by AS3 at any time.

Comment: I know about layers. My question is about static variables. But thank you for your time!